# Where does the minus sign go on Givens rotations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, rotations

I've been reading about using Givens rotations for QR factorization, but I've come across a small inconstancy between all of my resources. Some give a basic Givens matrix as
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
while others
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$
And it never seems to be explained if it matters which sine is negated. Does it matter? Is it a case-by-case thing where you have to figure it out as you do it? What is the rule?

Thanks for input!

Comment: It does not matter.  If you substitute $-\theta$ for $\theta$ you will get the other matrix since $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$.  So, it's just a matter of which direction you want to rotate in.

Comment: @Peder Ah! I see. I foolishly forgot that there's two directions you could rotate. Thanks!

Comment: Also, since the trigonometric functions are periodic, for every clockwise rotation, there is an equivalent anticlockwise one, and vice-versa.